# SQL Server - Group by - Additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a problem that I can hardly put in words and thus was not able to search for a solution before creating this post. Please forgive me if this has been asked before. Let me illustrate input and desired output:

```
Order    Description    Operation    OperationDescription    SubTarget
12       Order12        Op1          Order12, Op1            ABA
12       Order12        Op2          Order12, Op2            ABB
18       Order18        Op1          Order18, Op1            XYA
18       Order18        Op2          Order18, Op2            XYB
19       Order19        Op1          Order19, Op1            KLA
20       Order20        Op1          Order20, Op1            Truck123
20       Order20        Op2          Order20, Op2            Truck456
20       Order20        Op3          Order20, Op3            Truck789
20       Order20        Op4          Order20, Op4            Truck123
```

When I query the table above and group by Order and Description, I'd like to get all char from SubTarget (from left to write) as long as they match (and discard the rest):

```
Order    Description    SubTarget
12       Order12        AB
18       Order18        XY
19       Order19        KLA
20       Order20        Truck
```

I once found some neat code on the net to concatenate different values from a column not in the group by clause, using STUFF and FOR XML PATH. Not sure if that approach could be helpful here as well.

Thank you all in advance!

Regards,
Toby

Additional notes, based on comments and answer from @junketsu:
There is a column Target in the background, which is not accessible. Its content is always a partition of SubTarget - the other way around: SubTarget further adds some details to Target by adding more characters to the end of the string. That said, both values are not limited to two or three characters respectively. If so, I could easily use substring function.

The thrid example (Order# 19) might be confusing. I included this sample so show that it would be fine to the the whole string as a result if there were only one single operation in the order. 
Another example may be: Order 5 with Operation Op1, Op2, Op3 and SubTarget Truck123, Truck456, Truck789 and Truck 123. This should produce "Truck" as outcome. The repetition of Truck123 is no error. 
Hope this makes it clearer.
In the end I want to approach the actual content of column Target as it cannot be included in the query.

Thanks again, 
Toby

Comment: What is the limit of no of childs in a group is it 2

Comment: It would be much easier to handle this in a front end app.

Comment: And what happens when you have XYZ and ABC? Do you return nothing? Comparing substrings like you are trying is going to be extremely painful at best.

Comment: `ABA` became `AB` because `A` is repeating itself. If I am correct, then let us know that, why `XYA` and `XYB` changed to `XY`. Else explain your login with some example.

Comment: Very intersting comments, thank you all for your contribution! @SanalSunny, in theory there is no limit, in practice no of childs ranges from 1 to 10.

Comment: @TabAlleman, fair point and worth considering!

Comment: The situation described by @SeanLange won't happen, will update my question in this regard.

Comment: No @IdontKnowEnglish, ABA and ABB became AB since the string is identical including index 2. Same for XYA and XYB, XY is the commen part starting from the left side.

Comment: if new row inserted as `[20]       [Order20]        [Op4]          [Order20, Op4]            [Tru]`, then output is looks like...?

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish this won't happen, if order# is the same, at least the first two character of SubTarget are the same. This is because there is a 1:1 relationship from order to target and 1:n from target to subtarget.

Comment: @Toby.. see my [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502642/sql-server-group-by-additional-column/53518029#53518029) answer.... and let me know what you feel.

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish I think you are a genius. I run the query with real data and it actually worked. Kindly grant me like one more day to further understand the details of it and to do another test before I accept the answer finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant able to understand your **Additional notes and The thrid example (Order# 19)**. I just worked for your expected answer,

```
create table #group (Orders int,Description varchar (20),Operation varchar (20)
                     ,OperationDescription varchar (20),SubTarget varchar (20)
                    )

insert into #group values
 (20,'Order20','Op1','Order20, Op1','Truck123')
,(20,'Order20','Op2','Order20, Op2','Truck456')
,(20,'Order20','Op3','Order20, Op3','Truck789')
,(20,'Order20','Op4','Order20, Op4','Truck123')
,(12,'Order12','Op1','Order12 Op1','ABA')
,(12,'Order12','Op2','Order12 Op2','ABB')
,(18,'Order18','Op1','Order18 Op1','XYA')
,(18,'Order18','Op2','Order18 Op2','XYB')
,(19,'Order19','Op1','Order19 Op1','KLA')

select distinct 
gor.Orders, gor.Description, iif (g.c = 1, gor.SubTarget 
, left (gor.subtarget, 2)) subtraget
from (
 select distinct
 orders, Description
 , count (*) c
 from #group group by orders, Description 
) g join #group gor on g.Orders = gor.Orders
```

And I got :

```
Orders      Description     subtraget
12          Order12         AB
18          Order18         XY
19          Order19         KLA
20          Order20         Tr
```

Revert me, if query needs updates.

**Update 1** Find the updated query.

```
select distinct
orders, Description, Operation, OperationDescription
, iif (count (*) over (partition by orders, Description )  = 1, subtarget, 
       left (subtarget, 2)
  ) subtarget
from #group
```

**Update 2**

1). **cte**: First of all I take a sub-string of all subtarget.

eg: *Truck123->Truck12->Truck1->......->Tr*.

2). **countlen**: I count the pattern in **cte** and get max length. Because, basic string comes many times.

eg: *Truck* comes more time than, *Trunck123, Trunck456, Trunck789, Trunck123*.

And *Truck* length is greater than *Tr, Tru, Truc*.

3). **maxcount**: I get the maximum count, which are returned by **countlen**

4). At last I join above cte's without subtarget. Then which is got from **cte**.

```
;with cte as ( 
 select Orders, Description, SubTarget, len (SubTarget) len  from #group  
 union all
 select Orders, Description, left (subtarget, len (SubTarget) - 1)
 , LEN (SubTarget) - 1  from cte  where len > 2
), countlen as (
select
 Orders, Description, SubTarget
 , count (len) over (partition by Orders, Description, SubTarget order by len) count 
 , max (len)  over (partition by Orders, Description, SubTarget order by len) maxlen
 from cte
), maxcount as (
 select Orders, Description, max (count) maxcount from countlen group by Orders, Description
) select distinct
o.Orders, o.Description, c.SubTarget 
from ( 
 select 
 cc.Orders, cc.Description, max (cc.maxlen) maxofmax
 from countlen cc
 join maxcount m
 on cc.Orders = m.Orders and cc.Description = m.Description 
 where m.maxcount = cc.count
 group by cc.Orders, cc.Description 
) o 
join cte c
on o.Orders = c.Orders and o.Description = c.Description and len (c.SubTarget) = o.maxofmax
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go good sir

```
create table #temp_1
( [order] int null
,Description varchar(15) null
,Operation varchar(30) null
,OperationDescription varchar(30) null
,SubTarget varchar(30) null
)



insert into #temp_1 values

(12       ,'Order12','Op1',          'Order12, Op1'            ,'ABA')
,(12       ,'Order12',' Op2',           'Order12, Op2'            ,'ABB')
,(18       ,'Order18','Op1',           'Order18, Op1'            ,'XYA')
,(18       ,'Order18','Op2',           'Order18, Op2'           ,'XYB')
,(19       ,'Order19','Op1',           'Order19, Op1'           ,'KLA')


select *
from (
select *

,Rank_1 = Row_number() over(partition by SubTarget_1 order by [Order] asc)
from (
select [order],[Description]
--,SubTarget = substring(SubTarget,0,3)
,SubTarget_1 = case when SubTarget like 'a%b%' then 'AB'
when SubTarget like 'x%y%'then 'XY' else SubTarget end
from #temp_1
) a
) b
where Rank_1 = 1
order by [Order] asc
```

Comment: love the use of reserved words btw... NOT. Just a suggestion 'Order', 'Description' , Rank... reserved words of sql server. Best not to use them. If you really feel the need to follow it with a underscore or something :)

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks.

Comment: I'm sorry Order by [order] asc

Comment: @TabAlleman is correct, lenght of strings in column SubTarget is not fix and can vary from 3 to 20 character. Also the part that is identical can vary from any position until the second last.

Comment: then I suggest you start tweeking the code :) here to guide . Sample set gets what you want. Rest is your task.

Comment: Actually your code doesn't produce the posted output for the sample data. Order 19 should be KLA, this outputs KL.

Comment: sure; edited the answer. you can re-run the code and should give the expected resultset. Also added the case statements to handle varying length 'SubTarget' (add more cases how you deem fit)